# Problem with opening KivyMD (main.py file)

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, kivymd

I want to open the main.py file in KivyMD.  I have followed the steps in the video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kRWtSkIYPFI&list=PLy5hjmUzdc0nMkzhphsqgPCX62NFhkell&ab_channel=ErikSandberg
However, when I am opening main.py on the terminal with sudo python3 main.py, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window import Window
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'
```

I am using python 3.7 and am on Mac (mac book air).  Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

KivyMD is a library built on another library called Kivy. They are not the same library. You first need to install Kivy to be able to run KivyMD.

Please follow the below guide:

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-osx.html